# SELECT from table with count from another

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 2 mysql tables

```
View: id, name, description, userId
ViewUser: viewId, userId, role
```

I need to get all views by user, but also need to get the user role (for each view) and calculate a dynamic number of users used for every view.

So, I need to get all view columns, plus the role of the user which do this request (from ViewUser), plus count of users for each view.

```
SELECT id, name, description, userId, sum(usersCount), role
FROM (
SELECT v.id, v.name, v.description, vu.userId, count(vu.viewId) as usersCount, vu.role
FROM views v
LEFT JOIN view_users vu on v.id = vu.viewId
group by v.id, vu.userId, vu.role) A
WHERE userId = 33
GROUP BY id, name, description, userId, role;
```

With this example, I lost the counter for another users, because I use condition `userId = 33` at this level. I can do it in only a query, or I just need to use one extra more?

An example:

viewUser:

```
viewId = 1, userId = 33, role = 'admin'
viewId = 2, userId = 33, role = 'admin'
viewId = 2, userId = 12, role = 'viewer'
viewId = 2, userId = 16, role = 'viewer'
viewId = 3, userId = 33, role = 'viewer'
```

from this, I need to get 3 lines based on `userId = 33` condition:

```
viewId = 1; ownRole = 'admin'; usersCount = 1
viewId = 2; ownRole = 'admin'; usersCount = 3
viewId = 3; ownRole = 'viewer'; usersCount = 1
```

edit :

```
SELECT A.viewId, v.name, v.description, A.usersCount, B.role
FROM
  (SELECT viewId, count(*) as usersCount
  FROM view_users
  WHERE viewId IN (
    SELECT viewId
    FROM view_users
    WHERE userId = 33)
  GROUP BY viewId) A
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT viewId, role
   FROM view_users
   WHERE userId = 33) B ON A.viewId = B.viewId
INNER JOIN views v ON v.id = A.viewId;
```

This query get the results how I need. But I'm wondering if exists another way, optimized to do that.

Comment: Have you tried in same query ?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  You could also set up a fiddle.

Comment: What is **precise** MySQL version?

Comment: Akina, v8.0.22.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use correlated subquery:

```
SELECT *,
       ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT userId)
         FROM viewUser vu
         WHERE vu.viewId = u.viewId ) usersCount 
FROM viewUser u
WHERE userId = 33
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use following query

```
select t2.viewId,t2.role as ownRole,t1.usersCount 
from
   (select viewId ,count(*) as usersCount 
   from viewUser
   group by viewId) t1 
join viewUser t2 on t1.viewId = t2.viewId 
where t2.userId = 33
```